# Haskell のモナドに関するデザインパターン的なものはありますか？

Tags: haskell

オブジェクト指向は、それ自体はそこまで難しくない概念ですが、それを実際のアプリケーションに落としこもうとする際には考慮するべきことが多く、なので、 GoF に代表されるような、オブジェクト指向におけるデザインパターンが編み出されてきました。

Haskell で、プログラムの中心的な役割を果たすのはモナド(do 記法の syntax sugar がある、潰せる構造)ですが、それを実際のアプリケーションに落としていこうとすると、少し飛躍があるような気がします。

#### 質問

Haskell プログラミングにおいて、オブジェクト指向におけるデザインパターンのようなものはありますでしょうか。もう少し具体的にいうと、様々なモナドがある中で、それらをどのように組み合わせて実際のアプリケーションを構築していくべきかについてのまとまった考え方、のようなものはありますか？

Comment: 関連: オブジェクト指向におけるデザインパターンを各種型クラスと対応づけようとしているプロジェクトがありました。 https://github.com/thma/LtuPatternFactory

Comment: 類似質問?: [How do you identify monadic design patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8777216/5989200) -- Stack Overflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

よく知られたものとして、ReaderT Design Patternというのを挙げておきます。
実際にはReaderT以外の使い方についても言及しているし。

https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/readert-design-pattern

ざっくり言うと、

- アプリケーション全体としては`ReaderT IO`を使え
- その他の`IO`が絡まない、純粋な関数では適宜`StateT`や`WriterT`を使え

といった内容です。